# I want to add a loading png in LiveSearch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin for live search .. everything is working fine .. i just want to add a loading png that appear on start of ajax request and disappear on results .. 
please help me to customize the code just to add class where form id="search-kb-form" .. and remove the class when results are completed.

```
        <form id="search-kb-form" class="search-kb-form" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="wrapper-kb-fields">
            <input type="text" id="s" name="s" placeholder="Search what you’re looking for" title="* Please enter a search term!">
            <input type="submit" class="submit-button-kb" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="search-error-container"></div>
    </form>
```

This is the plugin code

```
jQuery.fn.liveSearch = function (conf) {
var config = jQuery.extend({
    url:            {'jquery-live-search-result': 'search-results.php?q='},
    id:             'jquery-live-search',
    duration:       400,
    typeDelay:      200,
    loadingClass:   'loading',
    onSlideUp:      function () {},
    uptadePosition: false,
    minLength:      0,
    width:          null
}, conf);

if (typeof(config.url) == "string") {
    config.url = { 'jquery-live-search-result': config.url }
} else if (typeof(config.url) == "object") {
    if (typeof(config.url.length) == "number") {
        var urls = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < config.url.length; i++) {
            urls['jquery-live-search-result-' + i] = config.url[i];
        }
        config.url = urls;
    }
}

var searchStatus = {};
var liveSearch  = jQuery('#' + config.id);
var loadingRequestCounter = 0;

// Create live-search if it doesn't exist
if (!liveSearch.length) {
    liveSearch = jQuery('<div id="' + config.id + '"></div>')
        .appendTo(document.body)
        .hide()
        .slideUp(0);

    for (key in config.url) {
        liveSearch.append('<div id="' + key + '"></div>');
        searchStatus[key] = false;
    }

    // Close live-search when clicking outside it
    jQuery(document.body).click(function(event) {
        var clicked = jQuery(event.target);

        if (!(clicked.is('#' + config.id) || clicked.parents('#' + config.id).length || clicked.is('input'))) {
            liveSearch.slideUp(config.duration, function () {
                config.onSlideUp();
            });
        }
    });
}

return this.each(function () {
    var input                           = jQuery(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    var liveSearchPaddingBorderHoriz    = parseInt(liveSearch.css('paddingLeft'), 10) + parseInt(liveSearch.css('paddingRight'), 10) + parseInt(liveSearch.css('borderLeftWidth'), 10) + parseInt(liveSearch.css('borderRightWidth'), 10);

    // Re calculates live search's position
    var repositionLiveSearch = function () {
        var tmpOffset   = input.offset();
        var tmpWidth = input.outerWidth();
        if (config.width != null) {
            tmpWidth = config.width;
        }
        var inputDim    = {
            left:       tmpOffset.left,
            top:        tmpOffset.top,
            width:      tmpWidth,
            height:     input.outerHeight()
        };

        inputDim.topPos     = inputDim.top + inputDim.height;
        inputDim.totalWidth = inputDim.width - liveSearchPaddingBorderHoriz;

        liveSearch.css({
            position:   'absolute',
            left:       inputDim.left + 'px',
            top:        inputDim.topPos + 'px',
            width:      inputDim.totalWidth + 'px'
        });
    };

    var showOrHideLiveSearch = function () {
        if (loadingRequestCounter == 0) {
            showStatus = false;
            for (key in config.url) {
                if( searchStatus[key] == true ) {
                    showStatus = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (showStatus == true) {
                for (key in config.url) {
                    if( searchStatus[key] == false ) {
                        liveSearch.find('#' + key).html('');
                    }
                }
                showLiveSearch();
            } else {
                hideLiveSearch();
            }
        }
    };

    // Shows live-search for this input
    var showLiveSearch = function () {
        // Always reposition the live-search every time it is shown
        // in case user has resized browser-window or zoomed in or whatever
        repositionLiveSearch();

        // We need to bind a resize-event every time live search is shown
        // so it resizes based on the correct input element
        jQuery(window).unbind('resize', repositionLiveSearch);
        jQuery(window).bind('resize', repositionLiveSearch);

        liveSearch.slideDown(config.duration)


    };

    // Hides live-search for this input
    var hideLiveSearch = function () {
        liveSearch.slideUp(config.duration, function () {
            config.onSlideUp();
            for (key in config.url) {
                liveSearch.find('#' + key).html('');
            }
        });
    };

    input
    // On focus, if the live-search is empty, perform an new search
    // If not, just slide it down. Only do this if there's something in the input
        .focus(function () {
            if (this.value.length > config.minLength ) {
                showOrHideLiveSearch();

            }
        })
        // Auto update live-search onkeyup
        .keyup(function () {
            // Don't update live-search if it's got the same value as last time


            if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
                input.addClass(config.loadingClass);

                var q = this.value;

                // Stop previous ajax-request
                if (this.timer) {
                    clearTimeout(this.timer);

                }

                if( q.length > config.minLength ) {
                    // Start a new ajax-request in X ms



                    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {

                        for (url_key in config.url) {
                            loadingRequestCounter += 1;
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                key: url_key,
                                url: config.url[url_key] + q,
                                success: function(data){
                                    if (data.length) {
                                        searchStatus[this.key] = true;
                                        liveSearch.find("#" + this.key).html(data);
                                    } else {
                                        searchStatus[this.key] = false;
                                    }
                                    loadingRequestCounter -= 1;
                                    showOrHideLiveSearch();
                                }
                            });
                        }


                    }, config.typeDelay);

                }
                else {
                    for (url_key in config.url) {
                        searchStatus[url_key] = false;
                    }
                    hideLiveSearch();
                }

                this.lastValue = this.value;


            }
        });
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a background to the loading class

```
   .loading {
     background:url('http://path_to_your_picture');
   }
```